# Solving an equation of real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have been given what seems to be a fairly easy task in calculus.
The answers in the book are not similar to mine, however.

$$
|7 - 3x| = -2
$$

I would assume the correct answer is: $$(0.6, 3)$$

The answer given is: "No solution"

The book has a reputation of having a rather large amount of incorrect answers, which is the reason why I am asking.

Thanks in advance for answer.

Comment: Obviously there's no solution since $|y|\geq0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Absolute value can never be negative. Do you know the definition of absolute value?

Comment: Can the post be edited so the suggested answer uses set notation (not apparently coordinate notation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $|x|$ is always larger than zero for any $x$. Essentially what the question is asking is

"For what $x$ is the absolute value of $x$ negative 2?"

Here we use $7-3x$ instead of $x$. The answer is that there is clearly no such value of $x$ that would yield a negative absolute value (because absolute values are never negative).

Answer (score 4):

The answer " no solution " is correct. 
The reason is that $|7-3x|$ represents the absolute value of $(7-3x)$ which is greater than or equal to 0. 
Hence $|7-3x| \ge 0 \,\ \forall \,\ x$ i.e. $|7-3x| \not = -2$ for any real $x$.

Comment: READ THE ANSWER CAREFULLY. It says $|7-3x| \ge 0$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry. Typing error corrected.

Answer (score 4):

The good thing about equations is that you can check your answers. You claim that $x=2$ is a solution. Well, let's plug it in: $|7-3\cdot 2| = |1| = 1 \neq 2$. So it turns out $x=2$ isn't a solution, and you can check that $x=0.6$ isn't either.

Now, I can't say much more without knowing how you arrived at your answers. But you can arrive at "no solution" immediately by noticing that no matter what the value of $x$ is, $|7-3x|$ can never be negative.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The absolute value of any real number can never be negative

Hence, in general $$|x|\ge 0\ \ \ \forall\ \ \ x\in \mathbb R$$

Answer (score 2):

I can see how you got that answer: you stripped away the absolute value signs, got the two equations $7-3x=-2$ and $-(7-3x)=-2$, and solved them.

However, stripping off absolute value signs can introduce spurious solutions.

It's just like solving radical equations: taking a power to get rid of the radical can introduce spurious solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will make it obvious that there are *no solutions*, sketching modulus functions (by hand) to solve equations is helpful even for trivial cases such as this.

As seen below, just to be absolutely clear the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ line is $x=-2$ and definitely **doesn't** intercept the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ lines which is $y=|7 - 3x|$:

[image]